# How to Pass Cognito JWT Token in HttpInteceptor in Angular

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, angular-http-interceptors

I currently have an application that uses Cognito for user login and authentication

This is what I'm using for the the user Authentication

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

export interface IUser {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  showPassword: boolean;
  code: string;
  name: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CognitoService {

  private authenticationSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;

  Tokentest: string = '';

  constructor() {
    Amplify.configure({
      Auth: environment.cognito
    });

    this.authenticationSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  }

  public signUp(user: IUser): Promise<any> {
    return Auth.signUp({
      username: user.email,
      password: user.password,
    });
  }

  public confirmSignUp(user: IUser): Promise<any> {
    return Auth.confirmSignUp(user.email, user.code);
  }

  public signIn(user: IUser): Promise<any> {

    return Auth.signIn(user.email, user.password)
    .then((user) => {
      this.authenticationSubject.next(true);
      let Token = user.getSignInUserSession().getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
      console.log(Token);
      this.Tokentest = Token;
    });
    
  }

  public signOut(): Promise<any> {
    return Auth.signOut()
    .then(() => {
      this.authenticationSubject.next(false);
    });
  }

  public isAuthenticated(): Promise<boolean> {
    if (this.authenticationSubject.value) {
      return Promise.resolve(true);
    } else {
      return this.getUser()
      .then((user: any) => {
        if (user) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }).catch(() => {
        return false;
      });
    }
  }

  public getUser(): Promise<any> {
    return Auth.currentUserInfo();
  }

  public updateUser(user: IUser): Promise<any> {
    return Auth.currentUserPoolUser()
    .then((cognitoUser: any) => {
      return Auth.updateUserAttributes(cognitoUser, user);
    });
  }

}
```

I then have a token interceptor service that looks at any http request and passes the jwt token in the header

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import Amplify, { Auth} from 'aws-amplify';
import { IUser, CognitoService } from '../cognito.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TokenInteceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {


  constructor() { }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    ///
    let token = localStorage.getItem('{the key for the jwt token}')
    let jwttoken = req.clone({
     setHeaders:{
       Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
     } 
    })
    return next.handle(jwttoken);
  }
}
```

My issue is that thus far I have getting the key for the token value that is set in `localStorage` using `getItem` and passing that key value into the header.

This does not work if I have multiple users as each key will be different.

How would I go about passing the jwt token via the interceptor no matter who is logged in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you mean with "This does not work if I have multiple users as each key will be different". Where exactly du you set the key to localStorage? This code was not included in your question.

Comment: When the user signs in there are multiple key-value pairs that are stored in local storage. One of these being the JWT key-value pair. The code for this isnt explicitly set, it is done during the cognito authentication process. The key value pair for the JWT token has the value as the token and the key changes depending on which user is logged in. So if I hard code local storage.getitem to look as specific key to get the corresponding value of the JWT token it will only work for that one user.

Comment: I assume the key is removed from localStorage once a user logs out and another user logs in, right? Shouldn't there be only one logged in user at a time or am I missing something? If not, couldn't you just use `return Auth.currentUserInfo();` (like you did in your `CognitoService` to determine which user key to look for in localStorage?

Comment: So the issue is that if I have two different users logged in at the same time and the key that the interceptor is looking at is hardcoded and user specific it will only work for one of the users. Im just unsure of what I need to do to get that JWT token that is accessible via my cognito service and pass it through my token interceptor service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should inject your CognitoService to your Interceptor as following:

```
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, from, switchMap } from 'rxjs';
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { IUser, CognitoService } from '../cognito.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TokenInteceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly _cognitoService: CognitoService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    //
    return from(this._cognitoService.getSession()).pipe(
      switchMap((session) => {
        let jwttoken = req.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + session.accessToken.jwtToken,
          },
        });
        return next.handle(jwttoken);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

and then in your CognitoService you have to provide `getSession()` function:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

export interface IUser {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  showPassword: boolean;
  code: string;
  name: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CognitoService {
  private authenticationSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;

  Tokentest: string = '';

  constructor() {
    Amplify.configure({
      Auth: environment.cognito,
    });

    this.authenticationSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  }

  public signUp(user: IUser): Promise<any> {
    return Auth.signUp({
      username: user.email,
      password: user.password,
    });
  }

  public confirmSignUp(user: IUser): Promise<any> {
    return Auth.confirmSignUp(user.email, user.code);
  }

  public signIn(user: IUser): Promise<any> {
    return Auth.signIn(user.email, user.password).then((user) => {
      this.authenticationSubject.next(true);
      let Token = user.getSignInUserSession().getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
      console.log(Token);
      this.Tokentest = Token;
    });
  }

  public signOut(): Promise<any> {
    return Auth.signOut().then(() => {
      this.authenticationSubject.next(false);
    });
  }

  public isAuthenticated(): Promise<boolean> {
    if (this.authenticationSubject.value) {
      return Promise.resolve(true);
    } else {
      return this.getUser()
        .then((user: any) => {
          if (user) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        })
        .catch(() => {
          return false;
        });
    }
  }

  public getUser(): Promise<any> {
    return Auth.currentUserInfo();
  }

  public getSession(): Promise<any> {
    return Auth.currentSession();
  }

  public updateUser(user: IUser): Promise<any> {
    return Auth.currentUserPoolUser().then((cognitoUser: any) => {
      return Auth.updateUserAttributes(cognitoUser, user);
    });
  }
}
```

One hint: You should also review your types. Setting `any` as a type is usually not a good practice.

Comment: Had to add .jwtToken to the end of "Authorization: 'Bearer ' + session.accessToken.jwtToken" but otherwise this worked! Thankyou!

Comment: ah yeah, sorry about that. I adjusted my answer!